# What is lw in Seaborn lineplot function

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I'm trying to understand the parameters for seaborn line plot by following the documentation -

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html

In the Code :

```
sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y, sort=False, lw=1)
```

What is 'lw' here signifies ?

Comment: It's an abbreviation for `linewidth`. It's not explicitly listed in the seaborn docs because `sns.lineplot` doesn't do anything special with it. These kwargs just get passed down to [`ax.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot).